# Оголтелый: при чем тут тело?

Tags: фразеология

"Оголтелым" называют того, кто потерял чувство меры, или какой-то безумный поступок. А при чем тут, собственно, "голое тело"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое мнение:

Исконно русское оголтеть — одуреть, от голта — разговор. "Оголтеть" связано с диалектным "оголчить" — "оговорить, испортить заговором, сглазить".

Русское голк «звук, шум», голка «суматоха», голчать «шуметь», церковнославянское гълкъ «шум», гълка «возмущение, мятеж», гълчати «шуметь», болгарское глък, глъча «произвожу шум», словенcкое golk «раскаты грома», golčati «говорить, звучать, болтать», чешское hluk, hlučeti, польск. giełk «шум».

Тогда галдеть, получается, родственно: 
http://enc-dic.com/rusethy/Galdet-5941.html
галдеть Искон. Суф. производное от галда < голда́ «шумный разговор», в диалектах еще известного (а вм. о в результате закрепления аканья на письме). См. глагол. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Вроде бы всё логично: голчить-галдеть, оговорить, сглазить, заколдовать. Стало быть оголтелый - это околдованный, сглаженный.

Comment: По украiнской мове : "Галдикати аю, аєш, недок., зневажл. Вести пусті розмови; говорити про що-небудь незначне, несерйозне. Довго гомоніли, галдикали,., дошукуючись — де ж справді взялася на селі ця таємнича Оксана (Вас, І, 1959, 239). " . ///// Тут корень ГАЛД- относится к "пустым разговорам"  , - И НЕ БОЛЕЕ ТОГО ! ... Чтоб связать по смыслу с <<ОГОЛТЕЛЫЙ>> этого , мне кажется , маловато . Русский язык в этом вопросе , по моему мнению , должен совпадать с украинским языком .

Answer (score 4):

Это слово, оголтелый, все этимологи дружно обходят стороной. Версия, приведенная в Вики, мне кажется не совсем верной (расплывчато-приблизительной) :

> Происходит от диал. о-голтеть, из праслав. формы *gъltati (вероятно, звукоподр.), от которой в числе прочего произошли: диал. голтать «бить, трепать», укр. диал. говтати «успокаивать» и др. Предположительно с тем же корнем - колгота «беспокойство». Использованы данные Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов (2007)

Слишком все предположительно, нечетко, хотя зерно истины все же там есть. Мне лично не нравится ссылка на "праславянскую" форму, которую никто и никогда не слышал и не видел написанной, тем более значение ее мы не знаем. Давайте искать в доступных нам источниках.
Представлю свое мнение.
В словаре Срезневского имеются слова :
**гълчати** - кричать;
**гълка** (=голка=глъка) - шум, мятеж...
Имя птицы - галка - очень подходит к данному значению древнерусских слов, ведь галки любят пошуметь, **погалдеть**.
Оголтелый - шумливый, мятежный, горластый?
Приходит на ум слово **глотка** - то, чем кричат, собственно. Оголтелый крикун - человек, любящий брать "горлом", нахрапом, без всяких там вежливых переговоров... Вполне может быть.
В подтверждение нашел еще словечко в СлРЯ 11-17 вв :
**глота** - толпа, скопление людей.
Известно, что толпа легко может стать *оголтелым* сборищем варваров.
Нацкорпус нам в помощь :

> Ф. Д. Крюков. Обвал // «Русские Записки», 1917 На пенистых гребнях освободительного потока увидела она рядом с героическим и самоотверженным обидный человеческий мусор, **в кликах ликования и радости режуще прозвучал оголтелый, озорной гам**, свобода забрызгана была напрасной кровью и ненужным, озорным разрушением общественного достояния… 
> мия не снята] ←…→
>
> Ф. Д. Крюков. В сугробах // «Русские Ведомости», 1917 Как будто реже стали характерные фигуры прасолов и скупщиков, **тех оголтелых рвачей с хищными глазами, со свирепо убеждающей, ругательской речью**, которые с налета засыпали флегматичного бородача в дубленом тулупе и папахе с красным верхом шумным каскадом прыгающих слов, ласковых и ругательских, умоляющих и издевательских, били-ударяли по рукам, орали, плевались, уходили и снова возвращались.

Answer (score 1):

*Голое тело*. В старые времена воины русичи в неравных сражениях, когда уже и надежды на победу не было, раздевались до пояса и полуголыми врезались во вражеские ряды. Как нож в масло. Ошарашенный противник зачастую отступал.

Comment: ))) Смешно. А ничего что слово "тело" писалось через ять? И что в "оголтелый"  "ел" - это образование суффиксальное?

Comment: Кто их видел , - этих полуголых русичей , что врывались во вражеские ряды ?! Только беллетристы в своём воспалённом воображении . В гражданскую , вроде бы , случилось такое , кажись , под Белой Церковью (если я не перепутал) : Котовсуий по тревоге повёл в атаку "голую" кавалерию , - они перед этим купались в реке и просто не успели одеться . Но это же единичный казус ! ...

Answer (score 0):

Вот, нашёл в **"Полном церковно-славянском словаре" Гр. Дьяченко** на стр. 127 /интернет-ссылка [ПЦСС стр.127](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0127.htm)/ слово <<**ГОЛОТЬ**>> **= ледъ, гололедица.** Скриншот см. ниже. Ну, на морозе человек дергается, дрыгается и, вообще, активно двигается и орёт, чтобы не замёрзнуть. То есть, внешне выглядит, так сказать, неадекватно. Исходя из такой манеры поведения и образовалось насмешливое прилагательное <<**ОГОЛТЕЛЫЙ**.>> Сопоставьте с <<**ОЧУМЕЛЫЙ,**>> - при симптомах чумы тоже наблюдается специфика поведения.

[image: Голоть - 1 .]

А также в Прибавлении на стр.947 /[ПЦСС стр. 947](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0947.htm) / с тем же значением.

[image: Голоть - 2 .]